# Dojo DateTextBox initial value

Tags: dojo

I use a DateTextBox field to display data from database. My problem is that not all the data is in correct date format. 
I need to display these data even if they are not correct but actually initial values are erased. Is there a simple way to disable this ?
I have a variable number of date in my page and it's difficult to override values programmaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to transform the dates on your server to RFC3339 format, it is possible to override the date widget to accept other formats.  See the second example "Alternate Date Format to/from a Server" on [this doc page](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/DateTextBox).